# Run-time error 2105 when accessing records from parent form button

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a parent form with a data sheet subform containing records. The parent form has a button that modifies the selected subform record by calling a procedure on the subform. The current record number is stored in a variable, the procedure requeries the subform which removes the record, and then uses the variable to go to that record number (which in theory will go to the previous record available assuming it's not the first or last record). There can be 100's of entries so it's important for the users that after the requery they aren't returned to the first record.

The same procedure can be called by double clicking any fields on the subform.

Relevant code:

```
Public Sub AddRemoveFromReport()
On Error GoTo ErrCheck
    dblLineNo = Nz(Me.CurrentRecord, 1)
    If Me.OnReport = True Then
        Me.OnReport = False
    Else
        Me.OnReport = True
    End If
    Me.Requery
    Me.Parent.frmPRJTrackerReportDetailTempOnReport.Form.Requery
    Me.Parent.frmPRJTrackerReportDetailTempAvailable.Form.Requery
    Application.Echo False
    Me.Requery
    DoCmd.GoToRecord acActiveDataObject, , acLast
    DoCmd.GoToRecord acActiveDataObject, , acGoTo, dblLineNo
    Application.Echo True
    Exit Sub
ErrCheck:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 2427
            MsgBox "Please select an item from the list before continuing.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
        Case 2105
            '// Last record selected, Go to the previous record instead
            DoCmd.GoToRecord acActiveDataObject, , acGoTo, dblLineNo - 1
            Application.Echo True
            Resume Next
        Case Else
            MsgBox Err.Description
    End Select
    Application.Echo True
End Sub
```

When double clicking any fields on the record the code executes fine, but when executing the same code from the parent form the run time error occurs regardless of position within the recordset. The dblLineNo has the correct record number, it just seems to fail when attempting acGoTo.

I've searched everywhere for an answer to this but haven't been able to find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot more testing I found the reason for the error.

Because the button is being clicked on the parent form it appears to not recognise `acActiveDataObject` when the code is run on the child.

The solution was to add `me.Childform.SetFocus` to the button routine prior to running the code. I also removed `acActiveDataObject` from the `GoToRecord` command. Just removing `acActiveDataObject` didn't resolve the issue and neither did just using `SetFocus`. I also removed the `MoveLast` line as it wasn't required.

Updated (slightly cleaner) code:

```vb
Public Sub AddRemoveFromReport()
    On Error GoTo ErrCheck
    
    dblLineNo = Nz(Me.CurrentRecord, 1)
    If Me.OnReport = True Then
        Me.OnReport = False
    Else
        Me.OnReport = True
    End If
    Me.Requery
    Me.Parent.frmPRJTrackerReportDetailTempOnReport.Form.Requery
    Me.Parent.frmPRJTrackerReportDetailTempAvailable.Form.Requery
    Me.Requery
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acGoTo, dblLineNo
    Exit Sub
ErrCheck:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 2427
            MsgBox "Please select an item from the list before continuing.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "JobMan"
        Case 2105
            '// First or Last record selected, Go to the previous record instead
            If dblLineNo = 1 Then
                DoCmd.GoToRecord acActiveDataObject, , acGoTo, acFirst
            Else
                DoCmd.GoToRecord acActiveDataObject, , acGoTo, dblLineNo - 1
            End If
            Application.Echo True
            Resume Next
        Case Else
            MsgBox Err.Description
    End Select
    Application.Echo True
End Sub
```

I hope this helps anyone else who may have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to update a single field of the current record only, so try this approach which doesn't require a requery:

```vb
Public Sub AddRemoveFromReport()

    Dim Records As DAO.Recordset

    Set Records = Me.RecordsetClone

    If Records.RecordCount > 0 Then
        Records.Bookmark = Me.Bookmark
        Records.Edit
            Records!OnReport.Value = Not Records!OnReport.Value
        Records.Update
    End If
    Records.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and code. I still need to do the requery as the record is removed from the list after the value is changed so unfortunately I can't really use it. I've found the solution to my problem and posted the result below.